# Как отловить ошибки формирования времени new DateTime?

Tags: php

подскажите как отловить ошибку

```
new DateTime('12')
```

**Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (12) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character' in writecodeonline.com/php:1 Stack trace: #0 writecodeonline.com/php(1): DateTime->__construct('12') #1 {main} thrown on line 1**

Если непровильное число то задать по умолчанию-`new DAteTime(10-10-2010)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new DateTime('12')
```

Это что? дата? время?
Лучше через [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php) делайте

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M', '12'); // 12й месяц
```

P.s. Если по делу: парсер в конструкторе не понмает с чем имеет дело.

**UPD:**
Извиняюсь. Я не правильно вопрос понял.
Если вам нужно отловить ошибку в формировании даты, то юзайте исключения.